# How to log res.locals content in console with ExpressJS and Nodejs for debugging?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, express, data-dumper

I'm working on an application using Node.js and ExpressJS and I'm a beginner on this environment. I have the basic need of logging the entire or partial  `res.locals`'s content in my console for debugging.

I've tried this :

```
var foo_route = function(req, res){

    var foo_data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.response.foo.length; i++) {

        // Here complex data management, not interesting in our case
        foo_data = // Bla bla ...

        // OK. This displays my object content
        console.log(foo_data);

    }

    // Seems because my misunderstanding of JS scopes, foo_data is still == []
    res.locals.data = foo_data;

    // Nothing. Both of these two solutions display nothing
    console.log(res.locals.data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.locals.data, null, 2));
```

I'm searching for a kind of [Perl's Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper), but it seems that I miss the point somewhere because it should be a very basic task...

Edit : I know this is maybe not specifically an ExpressJS or Node.js problem but much more a JS vars scope problem...

**Note for people who would read this in 2018**: don't use `var`, use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Comment: IF `console.log(res.locals.data);` displays noting then it must be null/undefined.  Can we see more code? Where you are doing it might be important.

Comment: @UpTheCreek, yes you are right. My problem seems to be much more about  variables scope isn't it ? I've edited the example code.

Comment: I'm thinking the way you determine the value of `foo_data` is actually very interesting, given that it's probably the reason your `console.log`'s are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `eyespect` module instead of `console.log`. It prints things in a way that is easier to work with.

```
npm install -S eyespect
```

When you assign foo_data inside the for loop, are you doing anything asynchronously? That could be a reason why things are not working as you expect

```
var foo_route = function(req, res){

    var foo_data = [];
    // what is data here? Also var i should technically be declared at the top of the function
    for (var i = 0; i < data.response.foo.length; i++) {

        // Here complex data management, not interesting in our case
        foo_data = ...

        // OK. This displays my object content
        console.log(foo_data);

    }
    // does this print anything interesting?
    inspect(foo_data, 'foo data outside the loop')
    inspect(res.locals, 'res.locals')
    // Seems because my misunderstanding of JS scopes, foo_data is still == []
    res.locals.data = foo_data;
    inspect(res.locals.data, 'res.locals.data')    

    // Nothing. Both of these two solutions display nothing
    console.log(res.locals.data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.locals.data, null, 2));
```

Comment: Full disclosure, eyespect is a fork of eyes.js https://github.com/cloudhead/eyes.js but with different default colors.

Comment: I've tried your Eyespect module, it's an amazing piece of software, quite the same than the Perl's Data::Printer (colored Data::Dumper). We will use it at work, it will be sweet for our eyes when debugging !